# how to fetch data from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

How can i fetch data from mysql database using php and trigger a mail to those email ids which i have taken from mysql database and also want to include two more data in the mail subject.NOt able to add code.can any one help me how to add the code??

Comment: How can I answer you while you have not tried anything?

Comment: "how to add the code?" - put it into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example code:

```
$headers = 'From: youremailgoes@here.com' . "\r\n";
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$output = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE x=?");
$output->bind_param("s", $parameter);
$output->execute();
$output->store_result();
$output->bind_result($id);
while ($output->fetch()) 
{
    mail($to, $subject, $emailcontent, $additionalheader);
}
$output->close();
```

Take a look at these links:

1. http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
2. https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

Try using a select statement such as this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and then use a mail system such as:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

References:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

This will allow you to select data from the database and e-mail information also.

Comment: Wuah, why not OOP for mysqli?

Comment: <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "sql", "234") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("AMC");
$tomorrow = mktime(0,0,0,date("m")+3,date("d"),date("Y"));
$three = date("Y-m-d", $tomorrow);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT PROJ_SPOC FROM AMC_INFO WHERE AMS_ED='$three'");
$ip="SELECT IP_ADDR FROM AMC_INFO WHERE AMS_ED='$three'";
$ipaddr=mysql_query($ip);
$serialno="SELECT HW_SERIAL_NO FROM AMC_INFO WHERE AMS_ED='$three'";
$serial=mysql_query($serialno);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$to = $row['PROJ_SPOC'];
mysql_free_result($result);

Comment: Why over complicate something? This user looks like he is just learning the basics of PHP and MySQL. This is the simplest way to do what he needs to do.

Comment: $subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello!
Find the below Ip and Asset.
$ipaddr
$serial
Note: This is an automated mail. Please do not reply.";
$from = "bi.des@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>

Comment: Ok then why not learn it the best way from the beginning?

Comment: I'm not going to complete your application for you, do some research, I've given you some links you can use, work with what has been provided and figure it out. You're not going to learn anything by people giving you the code.

Comment: The best way to learn PHP would be to use a framework where everything is integrated for him and learn the ropes slowly but surely. I recommend Laravel to this effect, no SQL to learn and mail is highly managed. This way you don't have to learn the intricacies of mail design, mail headers, and all that stuff and make things work easily!

Comment: OOP can become a complex subject to learn and OOP isn't necessarily the 'best' way.

Comment: OOP, generates cleaner, better code but you need someone experienced with you to generate good OOP. I've seen crappy OOP and excelent procedural code!

Comment: Can any one help me to edit my code?

Comment: I want to trigger the mail to the ids which i will fetch from database..and also want to use those data inside the mail subject..

Comment: Learn how to use forms in HTML and POST/GET methods, this will allow you to create a button and pass data from the form to PHP.

Comment: can you give me a link

Comment: You should really consider researching... I'm not your personal Google, this is the last time I'm sending a link. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp good luck