# How to get results from mysqli_fetch_assoc with table aliases

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am pretty new to PHP and don't know how to get results from the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function if my select statement has table joins and those joins are handled with table aliases.

The code looks like following:

```
$sql = 'SELECT T1.update_text, T1.created_at, T2.username, T3.group_name   FROM updates AS T1
        INNER JOIN users AS T2 ON T2.user_id = T1.user_id_fk
        INNER JOIN groups AS T3 ON T3.group_id = T1.group_id_fk
        WHERE T1.user_id_fk = "1"';
```

And the PHP Code afterwards:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["username"],$row["T1.created_at"]);
   }
```

For the "username" row I am not getting an error, but nothing is displayed. For the second one I am getting an Index undefined error. (This is only a snippet of the code)

Comment: where is your mysqli_query

Comment: As i have said, this is only a snippet. If I remove the alias, the code "works" but nothing is displayed...

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)

Comment: Yes, I have this statement in my code...but haven't posted it here.

Comment: username is empty in your database var_dump your row to see the contents

Comment: please update the code

Comment: No it isn't empty, I have checked it. Furthermore is nothing returned at all, from no table...and in all of them is data contained.

Comment: please echo $sql and check directly with table whether query is okie or not

Comment: So i echoed out the sql and one line, as expected got returned. Therefore lies the error within the table alias which cannot be read...

Comment: well it looks like you are right, but why does it not show me data within the while loop but with the var_dump?

Comment: Open the page source

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fetch data from mysql database using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287748/how-to-fetch-data-from-mysql-database-using-php)

Answer (score -1):

Change the SQL Query as following,

```
$sql = 'SELECT T1.update_text as update_text, T1.created_at as created_at, T2.username as username, T3.group_name as group_name   FROM updates AS T1
        INNER JOIN users AS T2 ON T2.user_id = T1.user_id_fk
        INNER JOIN groups AS T3 ON T3.group_id = T1.group_id_fk
        WHERE T1.user_id_fk = "1"';
```

then change the PHP code as following,

```
 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       while($row = $results->fetch_object()) 
       {
           echo $row->username.$row->created_at."<br/>";
       }
    }
```